# Response binary file takes too much time - Symfony 5 REST API

Tags: symfony5, php-7.4

Symfony 5 as REST API on a linux server (it's a shared host with cpanel).

I have a really simple endpoint that it is to download private files based on user privileges. The problem is that the endpoint takes too much time, i.e. for a 15MB .rar file the request took 45 seconds.

The response is:

```php
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse;

    $response = new BinaryFileResponse($path);

    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'private');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/x-rar-compressed');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $response->headers->makeDisposition(
        ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        $filename
    ));

    return $response;
```

And the problem effectively is in the file response, because if I change the response, for example, to this:

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;    

$response = new JsonResponse();
return $response->setData([
    'success' => true
]);
```

Request took 0.5/0.8 seconds.

I need to know if the time it takes is normal or because it is a shared server.

And the type of response is ok? All the files are .rar and rarely exceed 20MB

Answer (score -1):

When you process requests that can be lengthy, you should immediately give an answer - OK (request accepted), and start asynchronous processing of the file from the request.
Asynchronous processing can be started in different ways. For example:

1. Running Processes Asynchronously (https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#running-processes-asynchronously. )
   The process starts the Controller that processes the image file
2. Recommended: Queued Message (https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html)
   The queue handler starts the controller that processes the file.

The question remains: how to inform the user that his file has been processed?
You can use SSE and the Mercure component for this.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/mercure.html

Comment: Please share more details. How would your approach help to download a large file in a fast manner?